# Is there any way to fill half of a buttons background with a color?

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Is there any way to fill half of a buttons background with a color?

Like:

```
|BLUEBLUEBLUE REDREDREDRED|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in CSS with gradient backgrounds.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,0,0) 50%, rgb(0,0,255) 51%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,0,0) 50%, rgb(0,0,255) 51%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,0,0) 50%, rgb(0,0,255) 51%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,0,0) 50%, rgb(0,0,255) 51%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,0,0) 50%, rgb(0,0,255) 51%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0.5, rgb(255,0,0)),
    color-stop(0.51, rgb(0,0,255))
);
```

Use this site to customize it for your needs: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GNCRL/

Comment: make sure you are using IE 8+, because IE8 doesn't allow to set gradients pretty easily, you have to do exercise for that :)

Comment: Yes, the above wont work for IE8 and lower. For that your options are CSSPIE or chrome-frame, with the latter requiring a plugin download but is still way awesome.